# Why is my sequence constructor not working properly?

Tags: c++, constructor, sequence

I am currently working on a project in C++ where I must create a sequence and then perform functions on it. However, I have come across an issue with my constructor and I can't understand what is wrong with it. A new sequence does not get created.  I am using an array to implement my sequence. Also, I believe the issue might be in my `insert()` function as well.

Here is my constructor:

```
Sequence::Sequence(size_type sz)
{
    numElts = sz;
    elts = new int[sz];
}
```

This is my insert function:

```
void Sequence::insert(size_type position, value_type value)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= numElts; i++) {
        elts[i];

        if (i = position) {
            elts[i] = value;
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Instead of `new int[sz]` consider `std::array<int, sz>`.

Comment: Your array contains `numElts` elements. So the valid indices are 0 to `numElts - 1`. `elts[numElts]` is an overrun and undefined behavior.

Comment: You really need to work on your indentation/formatting in general. I recommend investigating [ClangFormat](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html).

Comment: @tadman `sz` doesn't seem like a compile time constant. You would need `vector` here.

Comment: The line with just `elts[i];` on it seems like it is missing something. As it is now it doesn't do anything. Perhaps work on a [mcve] se we can see all of your code and your intent.

Comment: Why are you using manual memory management and C-style arrays rather than `std::array` or `std::vector`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constructor is allocating an array just fine (make sure the rest of your class implements the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) properly, though), but it is not populating the array with any initial values.

Your `insert()`, on the other hand, has several problems:

- it is looping through 1 too many elements.  Arrays are 0-indexed, meaning the valid indexes will be `0..sz-1`, so you need to use `<` instead of `<=` in the loop.
- `elts[i];` doesn't really do anything meaningful. It is just reading a value from the array (in the case where `i` is the same value as `numElts`, it will read past the end of the array into surrounding memory), but it is not doing anything with that value.
- `if (i = position)` *assigns* the value of `position` to `i`, and then *evaluates* the result of that assignment (the new value of `i`) as a boolean expression.  So, if `position` is 0 then nothing happens at all since 0 evaluates as false, but any other value will evaluate as true and every loop iteration (including the 1 erroneous one mentioned above) will assign `value` to the array index specified by `position`, which can itself go out of bounds of the array since you are not validating it.  To compare the original value of `i` as-is against the value of `position`, you need to use the `==` comparison operation instead of the `=` assignment operator.

Try something more like this instead:

```
Sequence::Sequence(size_type sz)
{
    numElts = sz;
    elts = new int[sz];
    // or: elts = new int[sz]();

    for (size_type i = 0; i < sz; ++i) {
        elts[i] = 0;
    }
    // or: std::fill(elts, elts + sz, 0);
    // or: std::fill_n(elts, sz, 0);
}

void Sequence::insert(size_type position, value_type value)
{
    for (size_type i = 0; i < numElts; ++i) {
        if (i == position) {
            elts[i] = value;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

However, `insert()` can be greatly simplified by removing the loop altogether:

```
void Sequence::insert(size_type position, value_type value)
{
    // NOTE: checking for '>= 0' can be skipped if size_type is unsigned ...
    if ((position >= 0) && (position < numElts)) {
        elts[position] = value;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you this helped me out a lot